# Google App Engine - Too many Datastore Read Operations

Tags: android, google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore, quota

I have implemented an online leaderboard via Google App Engine for my Android app. But after 2 hours I reached 100% of my quotas in "Datastore Read Operations". Can anybody help me to modify my code to reduce the read operations?
Here is my code:

```
public class The_Big_Bang_Theory_Quiz_HighscoreserverServlet extends HttpServlet {
public void doGet(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse resp) throws IOException {
    String game = req.getParameter("game");
    String name = req.getParameter("name");
    String pointsStr = req.getParameter("points");
    String behaviorStr = req.getParameter("behavior");
    int behavior = 0; // 0 = upload, 1 = download
    if (behaviorStr != null) {
        try {
            behavior = Integer.parseInt(behaviorStr);
        } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
            behavior = 0;
        }
    }
    if (behavior == 0) {
        int points = 0;
        if (pointsStr != null) {
            try {
                points = Integer.parseInt(pointsStr);
            } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
                points = 0;
            }
        }
        if (points > 0 && name != null) {
            addHighscore(game, name, points);
        }
    } else {
        String maxStr = req.getParameter("max");
        int max = 1000;
        if (maxStr != null) {
            try {
                max = Integer.parseInt(maxStr);
            } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
                max = 1000;
            }
        }
        returnHighscores(resp, game, max);
    }
}

private void returnHighscores(HttpServletResponse resp, String game, int max) {
    DatastoreService datastore = DatastoreServiceFactory.getDatastoreService();
    Key gameKey = KeyFactory.createKey("game", game);
    Query query = new Query("highscore", gameKey);
    query.addSort("points", Query.SortDirection.DESCENDING);
    List<Entity> highscores = datastore.prepare(query).asList(FetchOptions.Builder.withLimit(max));
    for(Entity e : highscores) {
        try {
            resp.getWriter().println(e.getProperty("name") + ";" +e.getProperty("points"));
        } catch (IOException exc) {
            exc.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}

private void addHighscore(String game, String name, int points) {
    DatastoreService datastore = DatastoreServiceFactory.getDatastoreService();
    Key gameKey = KeyFactory.createKey("game", game);
    Entity highscore = new Entity("highscore", gameKey);
    highscore.setProperty("name", name);
    highscore.setProperty("points", points);
    datastore.put(highscore);
}
}
```

I read something about the `BlobStore`. Is it a better method?

Comment: Cache! If that's not enough, cache some more!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had the same problem, i used the cache mechanism from GEA to solve the problem.
Basicly the Cache is a Distributed HasMap

some code:
create the Map:

```
try {
            cache = CacheManager.getInstance().getCacheFactory().createCache(
                    new ConcurrentHashMap<String, Category>());
        } catch (CacheException e) {
            Logger
                    .getLogger(TipsDAO.class.getName())
                    .severe(
                            "unable to cretate cache using an internal ConcurrentHashMap");
            cache = new ConcurrentHashMap<String, Category>();
        }
```

For every read pop you check the Map first, if you find i there you return, if you don't find it you read from the DB and put it in the Map before you return.

```
if (cache.containsKey(cat)) {
            return (Category) cache.get(cat);
        }
        try {
            Query query = entityManager
                    .createQuery("SELECT FROM Category WHERE name = ?1");
            query.setParameter(1, cat);
            Category temp = (Category) query.getSingleResult();
            cache.put(cat, temp);
            return temp;
        } catch (Exception e) {
            LOG.severe(e.getMessage());
            return null;
        }
```

For every write op to the DB you also write to the Map

```
cache.put(cat.getName(), cat);
```

Comment: Thanks for your post! Can you tell me what "cat" is? And second, this line: "cache = new ConcurrentHashMap<String, Category>();" why is there no type mismatch? Cache and a Map?  
Best regards!

Comment: cat is a domain class of mine, it's all copy paste from real code... cache is of the type MAP, but it is a google implementation.

Comment: Is there a possibilty that you can send me the code (for example per mail) so that I can understand it better? Regards.

Comment: The full code i can not send you, but feel free to ask more info i will be happy to help. I will try to make my code example more generic tomorrow, maybe that will help some too. The idea is simple you use a Map to reduce the DB calls.

Comment: _I will try to make my code example more generic tomorrow_, that would be very helpful! I do not know if I have correctly understood the whole. If I put something in the cache, it is then stored in the datastore, too? Because you wrote _if you don't find it you read from the DB_.

Comment: If you store something you store it both in the cache and in the DB.

Answer (score 3):

Every entity returned by a read op requires a read operation.  You have 50k read ops under free quota.

You seem pull up to 1000 high scores whenever you get your high scores.  If you have > 1000 scores, then pulling scores 50 times will hit your limit.

Do your users really care about the top 1000 scores?  That's your decision, but I highly doubt it.  If you pulled the top 10 high scores, then you could have 100x more queries before you run out of quota.

The next step to save money is to use projection queries so your reads are using small ops instead of read ops.

Answer (score 0):

FYI, if you [enable the AppStats option](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/tools/appstats) of GAE, you can get a cool report that tells you exactly how long, and how expensive, each of your database transactions are.

This is pretty helpful when trying to debug your resource usage.

[image]

Comment: :Can you have a look at my appstats at https://dl.dropbox.com/u/27576887/stats.JPG It says the cost is 0, but datastore read operation fee is keep on increasing, now at 3.5 usd after 20 hours.